# How can I reference a javascript file with slim

Tags: javascript, slim-lang

I understand how to embed javascript using javascript: in a slim template.  Is there a way for me to reference a javascript file.

```
get '/about' do
  @title = "All About This Website"
  slim :about
end
```

here is about.slim

```
p This site is a demonstration of how to build a website using Sinatra.
javascript:
  alert("hello world")
```

that works.  Can I reference a javascript file instead of the javascript statment/s? like this:

```
p This site is a demonstration of how to build a website using Sinatra.
javascript:
  about.js
```

Comment: Just include a script tag: `script src="about.js"`

Comment: Can I use a file name with the javascript label?  

I will post another question on why I need to do that.  I realized this isn't specific to slim. I have the same issue when I use haml.

Comment: @Blender I've tried your solution but it didnt seem to work for me. I used a gem to convert my ERB files to Slim and everything seemed to work except for my javascrip files. Do you happen to have any other solutions? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I've used script tag to refer the file within the slim template and it works for me.

```
script src="jsfile.js"
```

The only thing we need to consider is, by default sinatra looks for **static files in public folder**, so keep the js file in the public folder. Try to access your js file from your browser. All files available under public directory should be accessible (without public in url).

```
yourhostedsite:port/jsfile.js
```

Your sinatra project structure might look like

```
Project root
    |___ controller.rb
    |___ public
    |       |___ jsFile.js
    |       |___ cssFile.css
    |
    |___ views
            |___ html.slim
```